# How to code 'scoped tabs' in Lightning Design System?

Tags: javascript, css, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, napili

I want to use the 'scoped tabs' component in a demo community on the Napili template. Example of 'scoped tabs' from LDS (Lightning Design System) at https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#scoped

I will be hand-coding the markup. The HTML makes sense. But I see in the description on the web page, it has some 'javascript needs' to move the .slds-active class and toggle the .slds-hide/.slds-show classes.

Does that mean it requires me to write custom javascript?

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately the SLDS is a CSS only framework and doesn't include any JavaScript to go with it.  Thus there are many instances where you need to write your own JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation

> JAVASCRIPT NEEDS
>
> The active tab has two markup requirements:
>
> - The .slds-active class should be placed on the li with
>     .tabs--{variant}__item.
> - The corresponding .tabs--{variant}__content
>     container receives .slds-show.
>
> Inactive .tabs--{variant}__content
>   containers receive .slds-hide. When the user clicks a different tab,
>   move the .slds-active class and toggle the .slds-hide/.slds-show
>   classes.

So you will need to write JS that handles placing the `slds-active` classes and the `slds-show`/`slds-hide` classes when a user clicks a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, as the Lightning Design System is a Pure CSS framework, we have to write our own javascript for the components.

I have written the code to handle any type of Lightning Design Tabs(default & scoped) in my blog [**here**](http://www.minerva18.com/blog/creating-switchable-lightning-design-tabs-in-salesforce/): http://www.minerva18.com/blog/creating-switchable-lightning-design-tabs-in-salesforce/

And It looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [minerva18.com](http://www.minerva18.com/Images/gifs/SLDSTabsDemo.gif))</sub>

I hope it helps, Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice and clear example of how to activate/deactivate tabs:

https://sfdcmonkey.com/2016/11/23/how-to-create-lightning-tabs-in-component/